# How t o get Google Now fetch info from Calendar?

Tags: google-now

Google recently announced "Now, just ask Google for your flights, reservations, package delivery info, and more
We can instantly fetch this stuff for you if it’s in your Gmail, Google Calendar, Google+, or Google Drive"
http://www.google.com/insidesearch/features/myanswers/

However, so far as I can tell, it only looks for this information in gmail, not the calendar, at least for me.

Is there some way to get Google Now to "fetch this stuff" from Google Calendar, or is Google's announcement misleading?

Answer (score 0):

Reminders set in the calendar will usually show up in google now. They do for my, I usually have a "notification" type reminder. Is the card enabled in Now?

Also, you can create actual reminders (with voice or text commands) that will create a Now notification. 
In the voice search, do "reminder: buy milk": you can then set the time period (evening/night/etc).

More info:
https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/3122344?hl=en

Comment: Reminders are different. Google Now provides lots of related information - see the link in my question http://www.google.com/insidesearch/features/myanswers/ and compare it to what your link describes